# Online like diff tool view for w3c.org documents

Tags: diff, w3c

Once I saw somewhere a sly link to w3c.org document. And it was suffixed by "diff" or something like, for instance: http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-api2/diff/bla-bla-bla.
And it show what was added, what was removed like in diff tool.

So my question is, how can I view diff between documents on w3c.org without externall tools?

Comment: Note that the canonical domain is `w3.org`, not `w3c.org`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for this service:

http://services.w3.org/htmldiff

(was found by googeling: w3c diff, second result).

Example: http://services.w3.org/htmldiff?doc1=&doc2=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2FTR%2Fselectors-api2%2F